# What does "Wide" vs. "Deep" mean in the context of Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

From this [article](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/), I read that "to accurately classify data with neural networks, **wide** layers are sometimes necessary."

However, I have seen many implementations and discussions on deep-learning, such as [this](https://skymind.ai/wiki/neural-network), mention the concept of **depth**.

What is the difference in the context of neural networks?  How does width vs depth impact a neural network's performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The width refers to the number of neurons in a layer. The depth refers to the number of layers.

Have a look at the following question regarding the impact of these hyper-parameters on the performance of the neural network: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/214360/82135.